# Removing disabled tint on UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibutton

I've my own custom button implemented and this works well.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class GhostYouButton: UIButton {
    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override var isEnabled: Bool {
        didSet {
            if (self.isEnabled == false) {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                self.titleLabel?.textColor = Constant.disabledGrayColor
                self.tintColor = Constant.disabledGrayColor
                self.borderColor = Constant.disabledGrayColor
                self.borderWidth = 2
                self.cornerRadius = 20
            } else {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                self.titleLabel?.textColor = Constant.mainGreenColor
                self.tintColor = Constant.mainGreenColor
                self.borderColor = Constant.mainGreenColor
                self.borderWidth = 2
                self.cornerRadius = 20
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I set my GhostYouButton to be disabled in the viewDidLoad():

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.nextButton.isEnabled = false
}
```

So it turns gray like I expect it to:

[image]

However... as you can see the title on the UIButton is faded out. I want this to be the exact same color as the border. How do I make this happen?

Comment: You need to add label above the button, you can set button text also. And may be your view hirarchy is not perfect.

Comment: It feels weird for me to add a label on top of the button if the button itself already has a title. Is this the only way?

Comment: @RutgerHuijsmans. i think you missing  super.viewDidLoad() into your override func viewDidLoad() .

Comment: add this `self.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue], forState: .Normal)
    self.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue], forState: .Disabled)`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik He is using label over button :/ I also suugest him to do same

Comment: I'm not using a label over a button. I'm just using a button

Comment: @no it is the button UIButton

Comment: @RutgerHuijsmans `as you can see the label on the UIButton is faded out.` Which label you'r talking about.?

Comment: Sorry adjusted the question. I meant title on the UIButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this line

```
   if (self.isEnabled == false){
    :
     self.setTitleColor(UIColor.gray, for: .normal)
    :
   }
  else{
    :
     self.setTitleColor(UIColor.green, for: . disabled)
    :
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, it looks like you are setting the title color of the label directly. Although this works, it is not the best way to set the title color when working with a UIButton as (as you are experiencing) this property can change depending on the state of the button. Instead, you should use the `setTitleColor:forState:` method of UIButton which gives you more fine grain control over the style and the appearance of the button as the button stage changes: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton/1623993-settitlecolor?language=swift

With this method, you can pass in a control state such as disabled, highlighted, etc: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrolstate